# How does the load on the tip a cantilever affect how long it continues vibrating after release?

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, solid-mechanics, structural-beam

I'm considering a situation in which a load is applied to the tip of a cantilever. After the release of the load, the cantilever oscillates, but due to an energy loss to the environment (which I think we can assume to be constant), the cantilever eventually stops oscillating. I am looking for a relationship between the load and this time, but I'm kind of lost as to how to begin modelling such a situation – could someone help? I'm looking for relevant variables, equations, conditions, etc.

I can answer questions below in case there is crucial information lacking. Thanks in advance.

Edit: any oscillation with displacement less than 1% of the original displacement caused by the load is considered no oscillation.

Comment: Do you have a criterion in mind for what “stops oscillating” means to you? Like is 0.1% of oscillation sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that's an important question. I would say that any oscillation with displacement less than 1% of the original displacement caused by the load classifies as no oscillation.

Comment: What do you mean by assuming the energy loss to be constant?

Comment: The rate of energy loss. In an ideal case, the rate of energy loss would be zero, and the cantilever would continue oscillating, whereas in this case the cantilever eventually stops.

Comment: You mean no matter how fast it moves, the rate of energy loss is the same? This will mean that it loses energy even if it does not move. What mechanism of dissipation do you have in mind? Usualy the dissipation forces depend on velocity.

Comment: Damping has a three case system, under, over, and critically damped. None of them are constant in nature however, ie have a constant rate of energy loss.

Comment: The load at the tip defines the initial amplitude. How that affercts energy loss is a complicated question and hard to model...

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a cantilever in a viscous fluid. For small speeds you can consider a damping term that is linear. Thus, the boundary value problem to be solved is

$$-EI \frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4}(x,t) = \mu \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2}(x,t) + c \frac{\partial w}{\partial t}(x,t)\, $$

with $x \in (0, L)$, $t \in [0, \infty)$, $w(0, t) = w'(0, t) = 0$, $w''(L, t) =0$, $ -EIw'''(L, t) = F$, and your initial condition.

Reading one more time your question, maybe you are not interested in a tip load but in a maximum of deflection there. In that case the boundary conditions are the following: $w(0, t) = w'(0, t) = 0$, $w''(L, t) =0$, $ w'''(L, t) = 0$, and you get the following initial conditions

\begin{align}
&w(x, 0) = f(x)\, ,\\
&\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}(x, 0) = 0\, .
\end{align}

There are several methods for solving this equation.